# Laravel: How do I get the last field from a different table?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables namely the Pt table and the Aktivitas table. in the index view I bring up the data from the two tables. column name pt from table pt. and the last update & user column from the activity table. one pt name has a lot of activity so that in the database there is a lot of content from the column updated_at & user.
My question is, how do I show the latest updated_at & users? because I've tried but my index always shows the last update & user from the first data.

my blade file

```
@foreach($pt_list as $pt)
<tr>
 <td>{{ $no }}</td>
 <td>{{ $pt->kode_pt }}</td>
 <td>{{ $pt->nama_pt }}</td>
 <td>{{ $pt->status }}</td>
 <td>{{ $pt->aktivitas->updated_at }} </td>
 <td>{{ $pt->aktivitas->user }}</td>
```

Aktivitas Model

```
class Aktivitas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'aktivitas';
    protected $fillable = ['nama_aktivitas', 'pt_id', 'tempat', 'tgl_aktivitas', 'jenis_aktivitas', 'dokumen', 'tenggat_waktu','deskripsi', 'status', 'updated_at', 'user'];
    
    public function pt()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pt', 'pt_id')->withDefault();
    }

}
```

Pt Model

```
class Pt extends Model
{

    const created_at = 'create_time';
    const updated_at = 'update_time'; 

    protected $table = 'pt';

    protected $fillable = [
        'kode_pt',
        'nama_pt',
        'status',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function aktivitas()
    {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Aktivitas')->withDefault();
    }

}
```

PtController

```
public function index (Request $request)
    {
        $pt_list = Pt::all();
        
        return view('pt.index', compact('pt_list'));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you trying to get something like `Pt::latest()->first();` ?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI yes, still can't. Trying to get property 'kode_pt' of non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another relationship on the Pt model to get the latest Aktivita

```php
public function aktivitas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Aktivitas')->withDefault();
}

public function latestAktivita()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Aktivitas')->latest()->withDefault();
}
```

Then you can use this hasOne relationship in your controller method query

```php
public function index (Request $request)
{
    $pt_list = Pt::with('latestAktivita')->all();
        
    return view('pt.index', compact('pt_list'));
}
```

Modify the blade snippet to use the new relation

```
@foreach($pt_list as $pt)
    <tr>
         <td>{{ $no }}</td>
         <td>{{ $pt->kode_pt }}</td>
         <td>{{ $pt->nama_pt }}</td>
         <td>{{ $pt->status }}</td>
         <td>{{ $pt->latestAktivita->updated_at }} </td>
         <td>{{ $pt->latestAktivita->user }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. it works!! so happy GBU!

Comment: it works. the latest record i've update its return on the blade. but if i update the first record with the same id that i've inserted before, the record is update but not return to blade view. it only display the latest record, not the latest update the record. please tell me how to do it

Comment: If you always want the latest updated record then you can specify like `return $this->hasOne('App\Aktivitas')->latest('updated_at')->withDefault();` in the latestAktivita relationship declaration